# How to stop the tomcat server on linux using java and JSch?

Tags: java, linux, jsch

I have a requirement in automation where I need to stop the tomcat server located at Linux.. How can I do it?. I am trying multiple code-snippets using JSch but those are not working as expected. Can someone please help me here?

Here is my sample code -

```
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("CONNECTED!");

        String process = serverGetprocess();
        LOG.info("ACTAUL SERVER PROCESS "+process);
        commandStopServer = "kill -9" + process;
        LOG.info(commandStopServer);
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");


        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(commandStopServer);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        channel.setOutputStream(System.out, true);
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0)
                    break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                LOG.info("Inside catch of channel closing!");
            }
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        return true;
```

Comment: You don't want to provide a remote facility to `kill -9` anything programmatically. This is not a tool, it is a weapon. There is no reason why a system administrator should not be able to login remotely and carry out whatever action is required, such as `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh`.

Comment: Somehow the shutdown.sh is also not working. Can you please provide me solution rather than digging into tool and weapon?

Comment: You are missing space: `"kill -9 " + process;`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to put within set command "pkill -9 -f tomcat" i.e;

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("pkill -9 -f tomcat");
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. I was not giving space in between -9 and tomcat.